# Only a single expression can be specified in the selection list, MSSQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that have this columns

```
  Name |  Country | Place | ZIP | Street
```

and i need to filter the records Like this:

```
SELECT Name, Country, Place, ZIP, Street FROM Addresses
WHERE Active <> 0 AND
Country IN ('FR', 'DE', 'PL', 'CH')
```

this is working but now i would like to filter the countries and the zip codes to the specific countries.

i have tried to do something like this:

```
SELECT Name, Country, Place, ZIP, Street FROM Addresses
WHERE Active <> 0 and
Country IN (SELECT Country FROM Addresses WHERE Country = 'FR' AND ZIP BETWEEN 'xxxx' AND 'xxxx')
```

unfortunetly i'm getting an error:

> Only a single expression can be specified in the selection list if the
>   subquery is not initiated with EXISTS.

(translated from german language)

why do i this way, because this query goes to the php. And a user can select which country and which zip code should be filterd to this specified country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a sub-select to filter the data of the query (as user specified).

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Name, Country, Place, ZIP, Street FROM Addresses
    WHERE Active <> 0 AND
    Country IN ('FR', 'DE', 'PL', 'CH')
) all_countries WHERE Country = 'FR' AND ZIP BETWEEN 'xxxx' AND 'xxxx'
```

To use multiple filters you can use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Name, Country, Place, ZIP, Street FROM Addresses
    WHERE Active <> 0 AND
    Country IN ('FR', 'DE', 'PL', 'CH')
) all_countries 
WHERE (Country = 'FR' AND ZIP BETWEEN 'xxxx' AND 'xxxx') OR
      (Country = 'DE' AND ZIP BETWEEN 'xxxx' AND 'xxxx')
```

Comment: and how can i apply this if the user make a multiple select like country `FR` and ZIP from xxxx to xxx AND `DE` with other zip ....

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a query which gives results and you need to add more filters, you can add on to the WHERE clause of the query .

In your case, original query was

```
SELECT Name, Country, Place, ZIP, Street FROM Addresses
WHERE Active <> 0 AND
Country IN ('FR', 'DE', 'PL', 'CH')
```

and you wanted to add `WHERE Country = 'FR' AND ZIP BETWEEN 'xxxx' AND 'xxxx'`

so you should simply add on to where clause like below  if you wanted to further filter all records

```
SELECT Name, Country, Place, ZIP, Street FROM Addresses
WHERE Active <> 0 AND
Country IN ('FR', 'DE', 'PL', 'CH')
AND 
Country = 'FR' AND ZIP BETWEEN 'xxxx' AND 'xxxx'
```

or if you just wanted to filter out zip codes in France then your query should be

```
SELECT Name, Country, Place, ZIP, Street FROM Addresses
WHERE Active <> 0 AND
Country IN ('FR', 'DE', 'PL', 'CH')
OR 
(
  Country = 'FR' AND ZIP BETWEEN 'xxxx' AND 'xxxx'
)
```

Notice I've used OR instead of ADD and separated out the full extra condition inside parenthesis to show that they belong together